# How to use Angular Translate to translate a string that has angular bindings with it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I need to use Angular Translate to provide localisation on an app that I'm working on.

I have something like this:

```
<p class="md-caption" translate="vm_stats_score"></p>
```

Now, I want to assign this to an ID that Angular Translate needs, but whenever I do

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
    vm_stats_score: 'Today from {{::vm.stats.votes}} votes'
});
```

It does not include the value that I want to bind to it.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/69) you can do the following:

```
<p class="md-caption" translate="vm_stats_score" translate-compile translate-values="{'votes': vm.stats.votes}"></p>
```

This will add the values you pass into `<p>` via `translate-values`.

As you can see in the example I could not get it to work with one-time binding. This means that you will have to change your string definition to:

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {
    vm_stats_score: 'Today from {{vm.stats.votes}} votes'
});
```

Comment: Yes! translate values does the trick. And the one time binding can be done like this `vm_stats_score: 'Today from {{ ::count }} votes'` and in my html i have `translate-values="{ count: vm.stats.votes }"`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind it directly, but there is another way:

In your translation file make variable for input, like:

```
{
  "vm_stats_score": 'Today from {{votes}} votes'
}
```

In your `html` pass the value,  like :

```
<p class="md-caption" translate="vm_stats_score" translate-values="{ votes: vm.stats.votes"></p>
```

[Example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LyQrVfDU4cCPECT4sNyV?p=preview) and 
[Read more on doc.](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement)